# Como centralizar panel dentro groupbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Como posso centralizar `panel1` dentro `groupbox` ?

Segue código:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // aqui defino novo size do panel1
    panel1.Size = new Size(591, 423);
}
```

O problema é que o `panel1` não fica centralizado.

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido:

```
panel1.Location = new Point(
    groupBox1.Width / 2 - panel1.Size.Width / 2,
    groupBox1.Height / 2 - panel1.Size.Height / 2);
panel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
```

Answer (score 0):

Também é possível alinhar pelas propriedades **.Top** e **.Left** dependendo é claro das suas necessidades.

Alinhamento dentro de um controle ou componente é uma coisa razoavelmente fácil. Vamos lá!

Sabendo que o centro do Contêiner localiza-se na metade de sua largura  **.Width / 2** e na metade da sua altura **.Heigth / 2**

**controle.Top = (Contêiner.Heigth / 2) - (controle.Heigth - 2);**

**controle.Left = (Contêiner.Width / 2) - (controle.width - 2);**

Obs.: o Contêiner nada mais é, que seu recipiente.